# Block content of Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, safari-web-inspector, web-content

To block web content I need to create an iOS background app. Which will get the URL address from any browser on the device, before loading the URL content check that URL by HTTP web service. Is there any way to get URL address from any browser on the device?

There is an app in app store [Shield](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shield-block-porn-and-adult-content-in-safari/id1102208660?mt=8), which can filter any safari URL before loading content. How does this app acquire the safari web URL to filter the content? Is it possible to acquire web URL of any browser from another app in iOS?

Please let me how to achieve that.

Comment: see https://www.hackingwithswift.com/safari-content-blocking-ios9

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you, i will try and let you know.